# SQL Server 2008 - Select query specific item

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I have a table with a bunch of columns, and I'm trying to run a query but I'm having a difficult time coming up with it. This is what my table looks like..

```
 clientID        Code
 -----------------------
 17              DAC7
 19              DAC8
 20              TIM19
 21              DAC7
 89              TIM19
```

So here, I have two columns (there are a lot more, but they're actually irrelevant). So the issue that I'm facing is that each client is supposed to have a different code, but there might be cases where 2 different clients have the same code, and that's exactly what I'm trying to find. If you look above Client 17 and 21 have DAC7, and Client 20  and 89 have TIM19.

How would I query this table to show me only the data where there are more than one instance of CODE, something like...

```
SELECT ClientID, Code 
FROM TblA 
WHERE Count (code) > 1
ORDER by Code
```

End result I'm hoping for...

```
 17              DAC7
 21              DAC7
 89              TIM19
 20              TIM19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this with an `IN` statement:

```
SELECT clientID, code
FROM T
WHERE code IN
    (SELECT code
     FROM T
     GROUP BY code
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY code
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd441a/6

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the following:

```
SELECT ClientID, Code, COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM Table
GROUP BY ClientID, Code
Having
COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get duplicate `Code` values using the following query:

```
SELECT Code 
FROM TblA 
GROUP BY Code
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Using this query as a derived table you can `JOIN` back to the original table in order to get `ClientID` field as well:

```
SELECT t1.ClientID, t1.Code
FROM TblA AS t1
JOIN (
  SELECT Code 
  FROM TblA 
  GROUP BY Code
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.Code = t2.Code
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a count() Over()

```
  ;With cte_1
   as
   (   SELECT ClientID,Code,COUNT(1)OVER(PARTITION BY code order by code) cnt
   FROM Yourtable)
   SELECT *
   FROM cte_1
   WHERE cn1>1
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, but you have to use `GROUP BY... HAVING` to get the duplicate codes:

```
SELECT   Code
FROM     TblA
GROUP BY Code
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

Then use this in a subquery or derived table to get the `ID`s.

Subquery option:

```
SELECT   ClientID, Code
FROM     TblA
WHERE    Code IN (SELECT   Code
                  FROM     TblA
                  GROUP BY Code
                  HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY Code
```